# How do you escape SQL data in CakePHP?

Tags: php, orm, cakephp

For some reason the [`AppModel->updateAll()`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/75/Saving-Your-Data) method does not escape data passed to it. Looking over the documentation though, I can't find anything on how you actually escape data with CakePHP.

Down in `datasources/dbo/dbo_mysql.php` I found the `value()` method that seems to just use `mysql_real_escape_string()` - but how do you access that method from up in the models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *most* of CakePHP's model functions you don't have to worry about escaping the input.

> CakePHP already protects you against
>   SQL Injection if you use:
>
> 1. CakePHP's ORM
>      methods (such as `find()` and `save()`) plus:
> 2. Proper array notation (ie.
>      `array('field' => $value)`) instead of
>      raw SQL.
>
> For sanitization against XSS
>   its generally better to save raw HTML
>   in database without modification and
>   sanitize at the time of
>   output/display.
>
> See https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html
>   There are other cases, however, when you need to run a custom SQL query or subquery.  In these cases you can either:

### Use Prepared Statements

```
$db->fetchAll(
    'SELECT * from users where username = :username AND password = :password',
    ['username' => 'jhon','password' => '12345']
);
```

### Custom Escaping with `Model->getDataSource()->value()`

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ' 
     . $this->MyModel->getDataSource()->value($untrustedInput, 'string') . ';'
```

The `value()` function basically escapes and adds quotes like this:

```
"'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data, $this->MyModel->getDataSource()->connection) . "'"
```

### Sanitize Class

This *used* to be an option, but was deprecated as of CakePHP 2.4.

Comment: While that's true with **SOME** ORM functions (crazy huh?) it's not true when it comes to the updateAll() method. However, that link you posted lead me to `Sanitize::escape(string $string, string $connection)` so I just need to figure out how to get the connection name.

Comment: I have the same question as the original question, did you ever figure out how to use Sanitize::escape?

Comment: @dereferenced To use `value()` method as describe in [link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) in Model, you can use `$dataSource = $this->getDataSource();` and then `$escapedValue = $datasource->value($rawValue);` In controller, use `$dataSource = $this->ModelName->getDataSource();` where ModelName is name of any model accessible from that controler.

Comment: @Meam your answer should be the real one~  You should post it as an answer and then let me give you an upvote!

Comment: Galen, I edited your post to include the other options as others have commented. Hope that's OK.

Comment: Warning: the exact support for prepared statements depends on the driver. For instance, as of Cake/2.x [Sqlserver supports them for reading but not for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45859985/raw-insert-query-with-prepared-statements/45860147#45860147).

Answer (score 4):

```
$name = "somename";

$db = $this->getDataSource();
$this->Model->query('SELECT * FROM models WHERE name = '.$db->value($name, 'string') . ';');
```

CakePHP cares also about quoting your input, because it is marked as a string.

```
SELECT * FROM models WHERE name = "somename";
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an alternative way of doing things, using Sanitize::paranoid:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-cake3/