# Equivalent mysql_real_escape_string in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.1

I want to upload a file with blob Field
I use a cake framework
But I cant use mysql_real_escape_string function
Please help me!

Comment: See this question for some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534243/how-do-you-escape-sql-data-in-cakephp

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking: You should not have to.

Cake assumes that you will use its ORM and not write SQL directly.

If you bypass that with [`query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) (which says *this should only rarely be necessary*) then see [Data Sanitization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/sanitize.html) (which it links to.

It reveals that you should use:

```
Sanitize::escape($string, $connection)
```

Comment: Sanitize was removed in 3.x and it seems that it haven't any replacement

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cake for your framework, stop worrying about `mysql_real_escape_string`. Cake already takes care of this. But I will recommend to have look at [Data Sanitization](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Data-Sanitization.html).

`**But to allow cake to take care of sql injection, you will have to use ORM methods like save(), find(), saveAll().**`

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build your own SQL string with CakePHP, then it provides the escape function as:
          `escape(string $string, string $connection)`

Comment: which is highly discouraged !!!

Comment: Which, sometimes, some external library requires you to escape for them, and I need to "borrow" the existing connection and escape function for the ease.