# Raw insert query with prepared statements

Tags: php, sql-server, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I have a helper library in `app/Lib` that needs to store a log so I'm trying `DboSource::rawQuery()`. Docs are pretty vague:

```
/**
 * Executes given SQL statement.
 *
 * @param string $sql SQL statement
 * @param array $params Additional options for the query.
 * @return bool
 */
    public function rawQuery($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->took = $this->numRows = false;
        return $this->execute($sql, $params);
    }
```

... and any example I find online pretends that SQL injection does not exist. No matter what syntax I try:

```
public function log (DataSource $db) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO log (foo, bar)
        VALUES (:foo, :bar)';
    $params = array(
        'foo' => 'One',
        'bar' => 'Two',
    );
    $db->rawQuery($sql, $params);
}
```

... I always get database errors like this:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ':'.

I've also tried positional place-holders (`?`) and even PDO-like params (with `PDO::PARAM_STR` and all the stuff).

What's the syntax to run a parametrised raw query in CakePHP/2.5.5 against SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is (apparently): none.

In the [source code for `Sqlserver::_execute()`](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/0b658697f2ad58ce96247d09e5b31b1c06dbee8a/lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/Sqlserver.php#L786) we can read:

```
/**
 * Executes given SQL statement.
 *
 * @param string $sql SQL statement
 * @param array $params list of params to be bound to query (supported only in select)
 * @param array $prepareOptions Options to be used in the prepare statement
 * @return mixed PDOStatement if query executes with no problem, true as the result of a successful, false on error
 * query returning no rows, such as a CREATE statement, false otherwise
 * @throws PDOException
 */
```

So **you can only use prepared statements on reading, not on writing** :-!

You need to get back to the early 2000s and *escape*:

```
public function log (DataSource $db) {
    $sql = sprintf('INSERT INTO log (foo, bar)
        VALUES (%s, %s)',
        $db->value('foo'),
        $db->value('bar')
    );
    $db->rawQuery($sql);
}
```